# GMail Snooze with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

As of July 2018 GMail supports a native snooze function (https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/07/new-gmail-ga.html). Snooze, referring to "don't show me that message until a certain day". Previously one was able to implement such a feature only with apps-script.

My question is: Is there a way to use the new snooze function with apps-script? My goal is to create a script that automatically snoozes emails from certain people or keywords. I would strongly prefer using the new snooze function because the old hacky way would include moving the email to a certain folder, then bringing it back to the inbox, but by that the email doesn't show on top in the inbox anymore.

Comment: Here are the Google Script release updates, but still nothing so far: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not. This is about Snooze (existing mails) not delayed sending.

Comment: DreamFlasher - my bad, I apologize (that's a canned comment that is auto-posted on a vote nowadays), for some reason I interpreted it is a delayed send feature, maybe I need more caffeine... Sorry for bad news, but I guess it is still not possible, not even via the API

Comment: 4 years later, still no official snooze support?